# Why is 'this' necessary despite capturing everything

Tags: c++, c++14

Can anyone explain to me why I have to explicitly write "this->" in the second lambda even tho I captured everything ?

The error message for completeness:

> cannot call member function 'result_t test::get()' without object

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using result_t = std::function<void()>;

struct test
{
    bool noMore = false;

    result_t get()
    {
        return [this]
        {
            std::vector<int> vec;
            vec.push_back(1);
            vec.push_back(2);
            vec.push_back(3);

            if(not noMore)
            {
                noMore = true;

                std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                    [&](const auto& i)
                    {
                        auto value1 = this->get(); // compiles
                        auto value2 = get(); // error
                    });
            }
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    test t;
    t.get()();
}
```

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/g/GA0EUv)

Comment: Are you looking for the formal Standarteese or just the rule of the land?

Comment: What happens when you change `auto` to `int` in the parameter list?

Comment: Changing the parameter to int seems to fix the problem. But why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a gcc bug. From [expr.prim.lambda]:

> The *lambda-expression*’s *compound-statement* yields the *function-body* (8.4) of the function call operator, but for purposes of name lookup (3.4), determining the type and value of this (9.3.2) and transforming *id-expressions*
>   referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using `(*this)` (9.3.1), the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct S1 {
>     int x, y;
>     int operator()(int);
>     void f() {
>         [=]()->int {
>             return operator()(this->x + y); // equivalent to S1::operator()(this->x + (*this).y)
>                                             // this has type S1*
>         };
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

In this case, `get()` should be equivalent to `test::get()`, and `this` is captured, so this is well-formed. clang compiles the code as-is. gcc compiles the code if you change `i` to be passed as an `int` instead of as `const auto&`, which is irrelevant to how `get()` is looked up.